# Laravel return cURL error 3: <url> malformed

Tags: php, laravel-5, environment-variables, guzzle

please I am storing the BASE URL for an endpoint in my .env file and calling this endpoint in my controller. 
When I do this:

```
$request = $client->get(env('URI').'/positions');
```

I get this error - cURL error 3:  malformed

But when I do this -

```
$url = env('URI');
$request = $client->get($url.'/positions');
```

It works. What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 5):

I solved by running

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```